# Sum of ng model not working in ng repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="marks in pagedItemss">
  <td>
    <input type="text" ng-model="marks.aaa" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" maxlength="3">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" ng-model="marks.bbb" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" maxlength="3">
  </td>
  <td>
    <span ng-model="sum" ng-bind="calculateSum()"></span>{{sum ? sum : 0}} 
  </td>
</tr>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.calculateSum = function () {
   var sum = 0;
   for (var i = 0;i<$scope.pagedItemss.length;i++)
   {
      sum += $scope.pagedItemss[i]["aaa"]+$scope.pagedItemss[i]["bbb"];
   }
   $scope.sum=sum;
   return sum;
}
```

Sum of `ng-model` not working. I given values as `(aaa:25,bbb:30)`, but it showing side by side values like `02530`.

Comment: can you post `pagedItems` values ?

Comment: Check this plunker that I've just made: https://plnkr.co/edit/2yRbexZtYHLbDBsSHNyH?p=preview. I think that's pretty close to that you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you are taking the value of an `input` element with `type="text"`, the value will be a `String`.

In JS, the `+` operator concatenates the strings:

`0 + '25' + '30' = '02530'`

---

One possible fix would be to change the input boxes to type `number`:

`<input type="number" ...>`

---

Alternatively you could convert the text values to a `Number` before you operate on them (there are many ways to do this is JS):

```
$scope.calculateSum = function () {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0;i<$scope.pagedItemss.length;i++)
  {
     sum += Number($scope.pagedItemss[i]["aaa"])+Number($scope.pagedItemss[i]["bbb"]);
  }
  $scope.sum=sum;
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Given      sum += Number($scope.pagedItemss[i]"aaa"])+Number($scope.pagedItemss[i]["bbb"]);    not working

Comment: @konda what result are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert string values to integers before adding.
Ex:

```
var a = "20", b="30";
var c = a+b
// c will be 2030
```

To get correct values parseInt() both values before adding.

```
var c = parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);
// c will be 50
```